# Symfony twig get data value from collection object

Tags: forms, collections, twig, symfony4

**Hello,**

when editing a form with obj-values from a collection in Symfony 4.2, i need each collection-objects ID for frontend stuff.

If I dump a collection object,

```
{{ dump(form.vars.data) }}
```

I can see something like this:

```
CollectionObj1 {#3341 ▼
  -id: 21167
  -value1: null
  -value2: 74
```

If I now want to access to the id with

```
{{ dump(form.vars.data.id) }}
```

I get the following error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a null variable.

Can somebody tell me, how I can access to the id of the object in the collection?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: same behaviour as described:`Impossible to access a key ("0") on a null variable` .
Without [0] (`{{ dump(form.vars.data) }}`) I can see a wonderfull output of all properties of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, two things I did not mention lead to the error:

1. My id is not called id. Due to an old database it is called someting like this: K_RESULTS_ID
2. I am using symfony's collection prototypes: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype and called the dump in the respective form-block

The first error was that you have to call such an id-name without underscores, it should be called like that:

```
{{ dump(form.vars.data.KRESULTSID) }}
```

The second one was, that I do have to check, if the object is not null, before fetching it. So I needed to add something like that:

```
{% if form.vars.data is not null %}
    {% set resultId = form.vars.data.KRESULTSID%}
{% else %}
```

Now it works like expected.

Thanks anyway, @wp78de and sorry for not posting the full truth ;)